# 'Function is not defined' when trying to call a function inside a contentScript

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-sdk

Addon code, creates a `Panel`.
`onShow()`, a list of files are read from local filesystem and populated into `Panel`.
When `<img>` next to a filename is clicked, I'm trying to call `Namespace.load()`, to send a message to my addon code, but i get `Namespace is not defined`.

Any ideas why?

`Data.js`

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
exports.get = function(content) {
    return data.url(content);
};
```

`main.js`

```
var Data = require("./Data");
var panel = Panel.Panel({
  width: 450,
  height: 300,
  contentURL: Data.get("html/view.html"),
  contentScriptFile: Data.get("js/controller.js"),
});
```

Error ..

```
JavaScript error: resource://jid1-xqhae0e9m07ekq-at-jetpack/addon-firefox/data/html/view.html, line 1: Namespace is not defined
```

`controller.js` (contentScript) ..

```
var Namespace = {
  load: function(filename) {
    self.port.emit("load", filename);
  }
};

self.port.on("uiData", function (uiData) {
  var parsed = JSON.parse(uiData),
    content = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < parsed.files.length; i++) {

    content = '<tr>';
    content += '<td>' + parsed.files[i] + '</td>';
    content += '<td><img onclick="Namespace.load(' + parsed.files[i] + ');" src="../images/load-24.png"></img>';
    content += '</td></tr>';

    document.getElementById('resultFiles').innerHTML += content;
  }

  document.getElementById("directory").value = parsed.directory;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used [Components.utils.exportFunction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Components.utils.exportFunction) since there were changes to execute environment in FF30 for content scripts, described [here](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2014/04/10/changes-to-unsafewindow-for-the-add-on-sdk/).

```
var Namespace = {
  load: function(filename) {
    self.port.emit("load", filename);
  }
};

exportFunction(Namespace.load, unsafeWindow, {defineAs: "load"});

self.port.on("uiData", function (uiData) {
  var parsed = JSON.parse(uiData),
    content = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < parsed.files.length; i++) {

    content = '<tr>';
    content += '<td>' + parsed.files[i] + '</td>';
    content += '<td><img onclick="window.load(\'' + parsed.files[i] + '\');" src="../images/load-24.png"></img>';
    content += '</td></tr>';

    document.getElementById('resultFiles').innerHTML += content;
  }

  document.getElementById("directory").value = parsed.directory;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think working code would look like:

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var panel = Panel.Panel({
  width: 450,
  height: 300,
  contentURL: data.url("html/view.html"),
  contentScriptFile: data.url("js/controller.js"),
});
```

You get the resource uris for a given file via self.data.url(). See the [docs on panels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel) for more info.

Comment: I use a separate module for `Data` api, for easier maintainability, so I already use `self.data.url()` .. see updated question.